# resizing range to enter array values into worksheet vba

Tags: arrays, excel, resize, range, vba

If I wish to take an array and enter it into an Excel worksheet, how do I do that?

If I use my code below, they go into the wrong cell (G5 instead of F4) and cut off the last column and row of the array.

I can add 1 to each of the resize dimensions (which will give me all the values I need), but then the data still only starts in G5 rather than F4. How can I get the data to begin from F4? (I've condensed the problem to this from a much larger spreadsheet where I'm not able to just simply use the next cell). Code is as follows:

```
Public ArrayToPaste(4, 2) As Variant

Sub PasteTheArray()

Dim i, j As Integer

For i = 1 To 2
    For j = 1 To 4
        ArrayToPaste(j, i) = Cells(j, i).Value
    Next j
Next i

Range("F4").Resize(UBound(ArrayToPaste, 1), UBound(ArrayToPaste, 2)) = ArrayToPaste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You were very close:

```
Public ArrayToPaste(1 To 4, 1 To 2) As Variant

Sub PasteTheArray()
Dim i, j As Integer
For i = 1 To 2
    For j = 1 To 4
        ArrayToPaste(j, i) = Cells(j, i).Value
    Next j
Next i
Range("F4").Resize(UBound(ArrayToPaste, 1), UBound(ArrayToPaste, 2)) = ArrayToPaste

End Sub
```

Just make ArrayToPaste **1-based** rather than **0-based.**